# Need help calling a method after pressing a button from a UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I have a UIActionSheet that I am able to successfully call from a UIBarButtonItem in my app.  However, when I click on a button that is on the UIActionSheet, the method that I am trying to get it to call does not appear to be called, and the UIActionSheet goes away.  My relevant code looks like this:

In my MapViewController.h file:

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>{
```

In my MapViewController.m file:

```
-(IBAction)showActionSheet {
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share your favourite restaurant with your friends" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"EMail",@"Facebook",@"Twitter",nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet release];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if(buttonIndex == 0)
    NSLog(@"You chose email!");
if(buttonIndex == 1)
    NSLog(@"You chose facebook!");
if(buttonIndex == 2)
    NSLog(@"You chose twitter!");
}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?  My personal hunch is that it may have something to do with how I am implementing the UIActionSheetDelegate interface.

Comment: Thanks very much for all of your prompt replies.  You were all correct!  Thanks for pointing out that oversight.  Take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share your favourite restaurant with your friends" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"EMail",@"Facebook",@"Twitter",nil];
```

should be

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share your favourite restaurant with your friends" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"EMail",@"Facebook",@"Twitter",nil];
```

And also make sure your .h file implements the `UIActionSheetDelegate` protocol

Answer (score 0):

You are passing nil as the delegate, but the delegate is your view controller, so pass self:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share your favourite restaurant with your friends" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"EMail",@"Facebook",@"Twitter",nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you forget to set the delegate , Add below in your code

```
actionSheet.delegate = self ;
```

From the Documentation ...
**The receiver’s delegate or nil if it doesn’t have a delegate.**

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UIActionSheetDelegate> delegate
```